# TensorFlow, how to automatically add run path to log dir

Tags: tensorflow

According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md), there should be a run-subdir added to the logdir, such as:

```
/some/path/mnist_experiments/run1/
```

Is there some way to automatically add `runN/` to the logdir for the smallest N such that the logdir does not yet exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not directly in tensorflow, but you can do:

```
import os
def get_next_run(path):
  id = 1
  while(os.path.exists(path + "/run" + id)):
    id += 1
  return path + "/run" + id
```

Comment: Yes, sure, but I thought that maybe there is some additional logic in TF, and TF would provide this handling for me, so better use this instead of assuming things and replicate TF behavior myself. So your answer implies that TF does not expose this functionality? Why does TensorBoard assumes it this way then? Is there any code somewhere which does it like this? Where?

Comment: I am quite convinced TF itself doesn't have this functionality. Why do you think that "TensorBoard assumes it this way"?

Comment: Because of the doc [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md).

Comment: As far as I read, this doc doesn't suggest that you can easily nor should create next runs as `run1`, `run2`, etc. You can name each of your runs as you wish, and tensorboard will still show all of models from subdirectories, which is actually quite convenient.

Comment: On the other hand, it would make sense for TF to check if directory exists and if so, increase/append the number to it. You can try to open the issue on github about that